# get vs. list in Kubernetes RBAC

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

What is the difference between the `get` and `list` RBAC verbs?

All I could find in the the documentation is this: 
"get (for individual resources), list (for collections, including full object content)", which I find severely lacking. Is `list` a superset of `get`, meaning if you have `list` permissions can you fetch all the information from `get` and more? While we're at it, what about `watch`? Does it only give permissions to read the change stream but not full object?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In practice, you can get all of the information you'd normally get out of `get` calls through `list` calls. However, having permission to `list` a resource doesn't mean `get` calls will work. You still have to use `list` calls and extract the information that way.

`watch` is a special verb that gives you permission to see updates on resources in real time. Having `watch` access without `list` or `get` is not very helpful because you won't be able to view the resource after it updates. Through `kubectl`, I was unable to watch a resource without having the `get` access to that resource.

To play around with these roles, I'd recommend messing around with roles in a Kubernetes cluster on [Katacoda](https://www.katacoda.com/).

Initial setup to make roles and grant them to (fake) users:

```sh
kubectl create role deployment-getter --verb=get --resource=deployment
kubectl create role deployment-lister --verb=list --resource=deployment
kubectl create role deployment-watcher --verb=watch --resource=deployment

kubectl create rolebinding only-get --role=deployment-getter --user=only-get
kubectl create rolebinding only-list --role=deployment-lister--user=only-list
kubectl create rolebinding only-watch --role=deployment-watcher--user=only-list

kubectl run nginx --image=nginx # Make a resource to look at
```

Then you can [run `kubectl` commands as one of the special users](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#user-impersonation) to see what limited RBAC permissions look like.

For example, the following commands show that we can only list resources with the `list` verb.

```
kubectl get deployment --as list-only # Prints out nginx deployment
kubectl get deployment --as get-only # RBAC error
kubectl get deployment --as watch-only # RBAC error
```

And this example shows that we can only get resources with the `get` verb (but you can get similar information by listing resources too).

```
kubectl get deployment nginx --as get-only -o yaml
# apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
# kind: Deployment
# ...
kubectl get deployment nginx --as list-only -o yaml # RBAC error
kubectl get deployment --as list-only -o yaml
# apiVersion: v1
# kind: List
# items:
# - apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
#   kind: Deployment
#   ...
```

Answer (score 11):

The `get`, `list`, and `watch` RBAC verbs grant permissions for different Kubernetes API operations.

You can see the corresponding API operations for each object in the [Kubernetes API reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/), for example, [here for the Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/#-strong-read-operations-deployment-v1-apps-strong-).

Here are some examples:

**`get`**

If you have the `get` permissions on the Deployment resource, you are allowed to execute the following API request:

```
GET /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/deployments/{name}
```

It returns the manifest of a specific Deployment.

**`list`**

If you have the `list` permission, you are allowed to execute these API requests:

```
GET /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/deployments
GET /apis/apps/v1/deployments
```

They both return a list of manifests of Deployments. The former, of all Deployments in a specific namespace, and the latter of all Deployments across all namespaces.

**`watch`**

If you have the `watch` permission, you are allowed to execute these API requests:

```
GET /apis/apps/v1/deployments?watch=true
GET /apis/apps/v1/watch/namespaces/{namespace}/deployments?watch=true
GET /apis/apps/v1/watch/namespaces/{namespace}/deployments/{name}  [DEPRECATED]
GET /apis/apps/v1/watch/namespaces/{namespace}/deployments  [DEPRECATED]
GET /apis/apps/v1/watch/deployments  [DEPRECATED]
```

They open a streaming connection that returns you the full manifest of a Deployment whenever it changes (or when a new one is created).

Note that the latter three API endpoints are deprecated, and you should use the endpoints for the `list` operation with a `watch=true` parameter instead. However, this still triggers the `watch` API operation and not `list`.

**Note 1**

Commands like `kubectl get`, `kubectl list`, etc. just executes these API requests under the hood. For experimentation, you can execute these API requests directly.

For example, first do:

```
kubectl proxy
```

And then:

```
curl localhost:8001/apis/apps/v1/deployments?watch=true
```

Or, you can also use this (doesn't require `kubectl proxy`):

```
kubectl get --raw="/apis/apps/v1/deployments?watch=true"
```

**Note 2**

In general, the permission don't imply each other. For example, if you have `list` permissions, it doesn't mean you can do `get` or `watch` requests, and if you have `watch` permissions, it doesn't mean you can do `get` or `list` requests.

**Note 3**

If you have only `watch` permissions (but not `get` and `list`), you can't watch with kubectl (`kubectl get deployment -w`) because kubectl makes a `get` and `list` request, respectively, before the `watch` request (to get the resource versions of the watched resources).

More examples in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58077113/4747193).